# How to compare the rows in a datatable and manipulate itto show in a particular format in C#/asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a data in data table with say 4 columns.Out of those 10 columns first column contains the date.The data in the table is in the form :
I/p

```
"15/12/2010",username,24,No
"16/12/2010",username,24,No
"17/12/2010",username,24,No
"18/12/2010",username,24,No
"19/12/2010",username,24,No
"20/12/2010",username,25,No
"21/12/2010",username,24,yes
"22/12/2010",username,24,No
"23/12/2010",username,24,No
"24/12/2010",username,24,No
"25/12/2010",username,24,No
"26/12/2010",Prakhar,24,No
"27/12/2010",username,24,No
"28/12/2010",username,24,No
```

We have to bind the o/p with the repeater.
For aforemenioned i/p the output should be :

```
O/P
"15/12/2010 - 20/12/2010",username,24,No
"21/12/2010 - 21/12/2010",username,24,Yes
"22/12/2010 - 25/12/2010",username,24,no
"26/12/2010 - 26/12/2010",username,24,no
"27/12/2010 - 28/12/2010",username,24,no
```

I.e. we are clubbing all the dates whose corresponsing column values are matching.
We have to write a c# code for it.

Comment: Sounds alot like a school homework assignment. Have you tried a loop, a list of clubbed data objects and build out the clubbed list in the loop?

Comment: @ Styne666 and @ Eric Brown - Cal:I took the count of no. of rows in data table and run the loop(Outer).I took two rows at a time and tried to compare the values.If the all values were coming similar , I moved to the next row(Inner loop).

Comment: For 15/12/2010  to  21/12/2010 the values of all the 3 columns are same (username,24,No) , so instead of writing 6 independent rows, I took an array and wrote 1 value("15/12/2010 - 21/12/2010",username,24,No) for the above 6.
After that I started the  outer loop from 7th row and inner loop from 8th and so on and so forth.

@Bob Horn :Clubbing means combining.
Asit can be seen from the I/P  For 15/12/2010  to  21/12/2010 the values of all the 3 columns are same (username,24,No) ,so instead of binding 6 rows with the repeater , I have to bind a single row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
First I have created a new Datatable for our final result:
DataTable dtInventoryTable = new dtInventoryTable();
dtInventoryTable.Columns.Add("RateDate", typeof(string));
dtInventoryTable.Columns.Add("RatePlanId", typeof(string));
dtInventoryTable.Columns.Add("RoomTypeId", typeof(string));    

private DataTable DisplayInventoryDetails(DataTable dtInventoryDetail)
{
for (int i = 0; i < dtInventoryDetail.Rows.Count; i++)
{
String[] row = new String[dtInventoryDetail.Columns.Count];
String[] row1 = new String[dtInventoryDetail.Columns.Count];
string str=string.Empty;
int h=0;
str = dtInventoryDetail.Rows[i][0].ToString() + " - " +dtInventoryDetail.Rows[i]0].ToString();                                                                                  
for (int j = i+1;j< dtInventoryDetail.Rows.Count; j++)
{                
for (int x = 1; x < dtInventoryDetail.Columns.Count; x++)
{
 row[x] = dtInventoryDetail.Rows[i][x].ToString();
 }
 for (int y = 1; y < dtInventoryDetail.Columns.Count; y++)
 {
 row1[y] = dtInventoryDetail.Rows[j][y].ToString();
 }
 bool result = ArraysEqual(row, row1);

 if (!result)
 {
 dtInventoryTable = GetRoomRateTable(row, str);
 i = j-1;
 h = j;
 break;
 }
 else
 str= dtInventoryDetail.Rows[i][0].ToString() + " - " + dtInventoryDetail.Rows[j][0].ToString();
 h = j;
 }
 }
 if (h >= dtInventoryDetail.Rows.Count-1)
 {
 dtInventoryTable = GetRoomRateTable(row, str);
  break;
  }

  }
  return dtInventoryTable;
  }  
   private DataTable GetRoomRateTable(String[] row,string str)
  {
    row[0] = str;
    dtInventoryTable.LoadDataRow(row, true);
    return dtInventoryTable;
  }
```